# how do I subtract values from two select statements

Tags: sql-server

I would like to subtract one value from another value. The schema of the  table is as follows:

```
   tag, datetime,value
   ------------
   tag1, 2010-1-1 10:10:00, 123
   tag2, 2010-2-2 10:12:00. 321

  select * from  

  ( (Select    Max(Value) as [Value1] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:10'       and tagname ='tag1') as v1   -

  (  (Select    Max(Value) as [Value2] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:12'      and Tagname ='tag2')  as v2))
```

obviously I am lost...how do I do this.

thanks

ms-sql

Comment: Are there always only two records?  If not, how do you decide which two records get subtracted from one another?  I.e. what criteria relates the records that makes you decide to perform the subtraction.  I would use this to perform a self join then you can subtract one from the other.

Comment: actually its the latest record and a record from 10 in in the past just to get an indication of the rate of change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Total guess:

```
select v1.Value1 - v2.Value2 from  

  (Select    Max(Value) as [Value1] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:10' and tagname ='tag1') as v1   

CROSS JOIN

  (  (Select    Max(Value) as [Value2] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:12'      and Tagname ='tag2')  as v2)
```

Comment: If there's only a single value in each query, then this would work perfectly.

Comment: @AaronLS yes, you only need GROUP BY on fields you are not using in an aggregate statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need wrapping select statement?

You can declare two variables `@value1` and `@value2` and substruct them.

```
declare @value1 int, @value2 int

select @value1 = Max(Value) as [Value1] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:10'       and tagname ='tag1'

select @value2 = Max(Value) as [Value2] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:12'      and Tagname ='tag2'

select @value1 - @value2
```

Comment: Thanks for that...I had tried that strategy, but I wasn't able to get it...I see the error of my ways now.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the value column? If it is already an integer just do:

```
SELECT 

  (Select Max(Value) as [Value1] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:10'       and tagname ='tag1') as v1   -

  (Select Max(Value) as [Value2] from History WHERE Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:12'      and Tagname ='tag2')  as v2
```

else you will have to cast it as an integer or whatever numeric type you want

Answer (score 0):

```
select h1.value - h2.value
from History h1
inner join History h2 on h1.Datetime = '2010-1-1 10:10' and Datetime ='2010-1-1 10:12'
```