# Subtracting two SELECT statements to produce a single result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did find this post: [how do I subtract values from two select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611174/how-do-i-subtract-values-from-two-select-statements)

but I cannot get it to work on SQL-Server 2008.

I have two basic SELECT statements. No GROUP BYs or anything, just a SELECT, FROM and WHERE.

I would like to subtract one of these SELECTs from the other. Both return one row and column.

Could somebody please help?

```
SELECT 
    ((SELECT Field1 AS BaseBase FROM Table1
        WHERE Field2 = 'something' 
        AND Field3 = 
           (SELECT Field4 FROM SEL_Function('something','something')) as tab1)
      -     
    ((SELECT Field5 FROM SEL_Function('something','something') as tab2)
```

Comment: what is this? `SEL_Function('something','something')` A tablename should be followed after the keyword `FROM`

Comment: You need to decorate the function calls with the owner (`dbo.SEL_Function()`) and the table aliases tab1/2 should be outside the select parens `(select ...) as tab1`

Comment: @Alex, I only added them in because of one of the answers I saw in that link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I don't think the cross apply is necessary fiddle won't allow functions but check out this fiddle.  You will want to swap out the table of the same name with the function.  I think you were getting bit by a combination of alias and paren mismatches.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc72f/13

Answer (score 0):

In the provided link there is

```
select v1.Value1 - v2.Value2 from ((bla) AS v1 CROSS JOIN (blubb) AS v2
```

which I would translate to this (in your case)

```
SELECT tab1.BaseBase - tab2.Minus FROM 
((SELECT Field1 AS BaseBase FROM Table1
    WHERE Field2 = 'something' 
    AND Field3 = 
       (SELECT Field4 FROM SEL_Function('something','something')) as tab1
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT Field5 AS Minus FROM SEL_Function('something','something')) as tab2)
```

Like stated in the comments, it would be advisable to specify the affected table. However, I think that it might work (I have no testing system at hand :( ) without those explicit definitions as well, because the names are unique.

Comment: Hi. It doesn't like the table aliases