# How to calculate the difference between purchase and sale quantity?

Tags: ms-access

How can I calculate the difference between the purchase and sale quantity in one query using Ms Access database?

My data, for example, looks like this:

```
ProductId Type Quantity
1         Purchase 24
1         Sale      1
```

How would I get the difference of (24-1=23) in one query?

Comment: info for you 24-1=23 :)

Comment: @wudzik you're not thinking out of the box

Comment: Does `"SELECT (SELECT Quantity FROM [table] WHERE ProductId=@productId AND Type='Purchase') - (SELECT Quantity FROM [table] WHERE ProductId=@productId AND Type='Sale')"` work? - or maybe something else from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611174/how-do-i-subtract-values-from-two-select-statements or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589070/subtraction-between-two-sql-queries

Comment: It Gives me Error: 
At most one record can be returned by this subquery

Comment: It Not Work On Ms Access Database

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table:

```
SELECT p.productId, (p.quanity - COALESCE(s.quantity, 0)) difference
FROM table p
LEFT JOIN table s
ON p.type = 'Purchase' AND s.type = 'Sale' AND p.productId = s.productId
```

Comment: i Have only One table that contain Purchase And Sale Product

Comment: @user2674803: yes, I know. My answer uses only that table

Comment: it Gives Me Error: 
Join expression not supported.

Comment: @user2674803: I'm pretty sure that even MS Access can handle joins.

Comment: i am solved the error.But it does not show any value if there is  no sale value of that product.How to solve this?

Comment: Use `coalesce` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the database name [DB-NAME]. 
and Columns and rows are something like.

```
[Table1]
ProductID      Quantity         Purchase         Sale
-----------    ---------        ---------        --------
1                1                 24              1
2                100               50              10
```

**If you want to calculate the [Purchase] - [Sale] for a specific Product id Use:**

`( Select (Purchase - Sale) AS MyNumber FROM[DB-Name].[Table1] WHERE (ProductID=1))`

> //where 1 is your product id

The result table will be

```
MyNumber
--------
23
```

**if you want to calculate the totals for all [ProductID] Use:**

```
  (Select (SUM(Purchase) - Sum(Sale)) AS MyNumber FROM[DB-Name].[Table1] )
```

The result table will be

```
MyNumber
--------
63
```

Comment: There is No Purchase AND Sale Columns in my table,There Is Type Columns that conatails a row Purchase And Sale